# Jquery function creates an anomolous pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: created a fiddle which shows the problem https://jsfiddle.net/MichaelCaley/wcoba1jy/

The below code creates a 7 second pause between each fade until we get to the end where the code re runs itself. For some reason this delay becomes 14/15 seconds.

I have done a lot of searching but come up with trump all, so any help is appreciated.

```
    var imgshow = function(){
    $(".img1").delay(7000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
        $(".img2").delay(7000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
            $(".img1").delay(7000).fadeIn(1500, function(){
                $(".img2").delay(7000).fadeIn(1500, function(){
                    imgshow();
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
imgshow();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a problem with the above code. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/egnkgmwr/ (I've sped it up by a factor of 10) - right corner has seconds between the calls.

Comment: Hi Potato, thanks for the feedback. After looking at your fiddle I decided to see if I could recreate the problem, and I have. https://jsfiddle.net/MichaelCaley/wcoba1jy/ you will see that from the second loop the first square takes longer to fade out

Comment: Ah. I think I see the problem - check out the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually functioning as coded (but probably not as you intended :-)). What's happening is that the 2nd `fadeIn` has (visually) no effect because img2 is under img1 (which is fully opaque) causing img1 to stay twice as long.

Hopefully the following makes it clear - 1 indicates fully opaque and 0 indicates fully transparent

- img3 (1) under img2 (1) under img1 (1) => img1 shown
- img3 (1) under img2 (1) under img1 (0) => img2 shown
- img3 (1) under img2 (0) under img1 (0) => img3 shown
- img3 (1) under img2 (0) under img1 (1) => img1 shown
- img3 (1) under img2 (1) under img1 (1) => img1 shown (when you probably want img2)
  ...

If you swap the last 2 `fadeIn`, you'll get something that changes color every interval (https://jsfiddle.net/xx303tdc/) but the sequence will be img1, img2, img3, img2, img1... Otherwise you could just set img2 to be fully visible after the img1 `fadeIn` and then restart the loop.

In any case, because you are doing a recursive call, you'll eventually run out of stackspace (very slowly because of the delay), so it might be a good idea to refactor to use CSS transitions.

Comment: You're totally right and even before I finished reading your answer I could see the issue. In reference to the stackspace issue you mentioned, is that a problem with any looped function? Or is there a way that I am supposed to be doing it?

Comment: Its a problem with any recursive function that doesn't end - but I don't know enough to definitively say that it will be a problem in this case (a 7s delay is usually ok. assuming the user doesn't spend hours on the page). Anyhow if you are just looking to change the background you can do it with pure CSS - see https://jsfiddle.net/mrwq20ct/